# awk - calculate the mean age if condition is met

Tags: awk

I'm trying to calculate with awk the mean age of all users in the shown list that fulfill the requirement of speaking spanish, being 'native_lang' or 'other_lan'.

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
24,F,21,finnish,english swedish spanish 
25,F,26,finnish,english swedish
26,M,20,polish,english spanish finnish 
27,M,25,finnish,english french 
28,F,21,russian,finnish english french 
29,F,28,finnish,english swedish
30,F,19,finnish,english swedish french spanish 
31,O,40,finnish,swedish english german russian lithuanian portuguese
32,F,22,finnish,swedish english french
33,M,26,spanish,english german french
34,F,20,finnish,swedish english german
```

I started the code like this, but I'm not sure wether `count` can be used to sum the content of a variable.

```
awk -F ',' '$4~/spanish/ || $5~/spanish/ {count $3} 
            END {printf("%.2f%\n", ??????)}'
```

The expected result should be shown as follows: `21.50`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In any other programming language you can think of, how would you add the value stored in `$3` to a variable named `count`? Why not try that in awk too? Ditto for using `printf` to print the value of a variable.

Comment: @EdMorton, I am new user in programming so, it's being quite difficult to me to figure out how to assign the value

Comment: fwiw, a google search on `awk calculate mean average` will bring up a lot of hits, most of which demonstrate basic operations like incrementing variables, adding to variables, performing  mean/average calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good start, but save both the total and the count

```
awk -F ',' '$4~/spanish/ || $5~/spanish/ {count++;tot+= $3} 
            END {printf("%.2f\n", tot/count)}'
```

Comment: Note that if there is no match for spanish, you will divide by 0 and get `division by zero attempted`